# Insert query into a specific cell based on a dynamic reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

I have 4 queries.  The amount of results from each will vary week-by-week.

I have a formula to calculate the number of rows of each query.

I want the queries set out in the Google Sheet so that the user can scroll down through the 4 sets of results, ideally 'one after the other', without 'artificially made gaps' in-between.  (Although I cannot be certain how many results each query will provide, there is a rough upper limit which I have used a guideline to create those 'gaps'

Is there a way of somehow dynamically assigning my queries into particular cells, based on the number of results in each?

E.G. If I use my formula to calculate results from a query, I know that my first query will have 10 results, therefore I want the second query to be inserted into A11.  BUT, next week, there might be 15 results in that first query, so I would want the query inserted into A16.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always difficult to assess a problem or offer accurate solutions unless you share a link to your sheet (or a copy of your sheet). However, based on what you've said, I can tell you that you *can* combine QUERY formulas vertically in this way:

```
={
QUERY(A:B,"Select * Where B = 'Adam'",0);
QUERY(A:B,"Select * Where B = 'Joe'",0);
QUERY(A:B,"Select * Where B = 'Sally'",0)
}
```

I only separated the formula into lines for clarity; there's not need to do this in real-world application.

NOTES:

1. The outer curly brackets signify an array.
2. The semicolon means, in English, "Put the next element of the array directly below."
3. The comma-zero at the end of each QUERY tells the QUERY that there are no headers; so you can leave that off or make it a comma-one for the first query if you want to include its headers.

You can also combine with OR:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"Select * Where B = 'Adam' OR B = 'Joe' OR B = 'Sally'",0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately, it's a project for a school and it would take me a while to change the data sufficiently to make it OK to share with the public.  Thanks once more for your solution and I'll give it a go.

Comment: Again, it's hard to know what your real-world application will be (e.g., will you be trying to combine for 3 names each time, or 30? Will they be the same names all the time, or will they differ daily?) And there would be different approaches for each case. Note my addition to my posted answer at the bottom, which, based on your case, may save you time.